# How can I export numpy array in scientific notation for all numbered columns and string when text column (varying position) exists in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have dynamic (shape changes) arrays in which the text column changes and does not have a fixed position. I am trying to save these arrays in an output file such that the numbers are in scientific notation. However, when the columns are text they should be output as such.

A MWE is given below:

MWE

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 1.00E-07, 2.43E-03, 2.76E-03],
              [2, 1.25E-07, 3.03E-03, 3.45E-03], 
              [3, 1.56E-07, 3.79E-03, 4.31E-03]])

B = np.array([[1, 1.00E-07, 2.43E-03, 2.76E-03, 3.11E-03, 'P', 1.66E+01],
              [2, 1.25E-07, 3.03E-03, 3.45E-03, 3.89E-03, 'Q', 1.32E+00], 
              [3, 1.56E-07, 3.79E-03, 4.31E-03, 4.86E-03, 'R', 1.29E+00]])

C = np.array([[1, 1.00E-07, 2.43E-03, 'A', 3.11E-03, 2.85E-01],
              [2, 1.25E-07, 3.03E-03, 'B', 3.89E-03, 3.56E-01],
              [3, 1.56E-07, 3.79E-03, 'C', 4.86E-03, 4.45E-01]])

for i in ['A', 'B','C']:
    np.savetxt('array_' + str(i) + '.txt',vars()[i], fmt = '%0.6E', delimiter = '\t')
```

How can I export numpy array in scientific notation for all numbered columns and string when text column (varying position) exists in Python?

Comment: You can specify a different `fmt` for each column, including `%s` for the strings.  But Your arrays, as constructed, have uniform dtypes.  Print them to see that.  You'll need to construct either structured arrays, or object dtype arrays.

Comment: The arrays are of varying nature, they change in shape and the position of text column also changes.